# Office 2013 - VBA Email does not display To/CC/BCC variables

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I am creating emails from Excel via the VBA Outlook.Application Reference. Each email is populated with data from my excel sheet and then placed into the To/CC/BCC/Subject/Body fields.

Now, when running this code in Office 2010 it works without a hitch, but in Office 2013 the variables containing the To/CC/BCC/etc. data does not show up in the actual email when displayed.

Did this reference change in Office 2013?

```
    Sub MailSheet()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim outMail As Object
    Dim rng As Range

    ' set required variables
    Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set Property = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Range("B4")
    Set Holidex = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Range("B5")
    Set SendTo = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Range("B29")
    Set SendCC = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Range("B30")
    Set rng = Sheets("Mail").Range("A1:F80")

    ' set email variables
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set outMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

' some code

        ' get ready to mail
        With outMail
            .To = SendTo
            .ReplyRecipients.Add ""
            .CC = SendCC
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = Holidex & " - Daily Email"
            .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)

            ' display email before sending
            .Display   '.Send or use .Display
        End With

' some code

    ' Clean up
    Set outMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

end Sub
```

Comment: Firstly, do not add an empty string to the reply recipients. Secondly, do yo use a different result if you use Recipients.Add instead of setting the To/CC/BCC properties?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I can help you directly, but I do have some code I found online which I know for a fact works with Outlook 2016, will share it on here in case it helps:

```
Sub OutlookMail_1()
'Automate Sending Emails from Excel, using Outlook.
'Send text and also contents from the host workbook's worksheet range
' as Mail Body, and add an attachment with the mail.
'Automating using Early Binding: Add a reference to the Outlook Object Library
' in Excel (your host application) by clicking Tools-References in VBE,
' which will enable using Outlook's predefined constants.
'Once this reference is added, a new instance of
' Outlook application can be created by using the New keyword.

'variables declared as a specific object type
'  ie. specific to the application which is being automated:
Dim applOL As Outlook.Application
Dim miOL As Outlook.MailItem
Dim recptOL As Outlook.Recipient
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim name As String
Dim email As String
Dim nominees As Range
Dim number As String

'set worksheet:
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

'Create a new instance of the Outlook application.
' Set the Application object as follows:
Set applOL = New Outlook.Application

'create mail item:
Set miOL = applOL.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'Add mail recipients, either the email id or their name in your address book.
' Invalid ids will result in code error.
Set recptOL = miOL.Recipients.Add("Main recipient email")
recptOL.Type = olTo

Set recptOL = miOL.Recipients.Add("BCC Email")
recptOL.Type = olbcc

Set recptOL = miOL.Recipients.Add("BCC Email")
recptOL.Type = olbcc

Set recptOL = miOL.Recipients.Add("BCC Email")
recptOL.Type = olbcc

'with the mail item:
With miOL

'subject of the mail:
.Subject = "Subject"    

'Chr(10) represents line feed/new line, & Chr(13) represents carriage return.

' Send text and also contents from
'  the host workbook's worksheet range as Mail Body.
.Body = "BODY OF EMAIL"

'set importance level for the mail:
.Importance = olImportanceHigh
'add an attachment to the mail:

'send the mail:

.Display

End With  

'clear the object variables:
Set applOL = Nothing
Set miOL = Nothing
Set recptOL = Nothing 

End Sub
```

Some of the variables I set are redundant because I edited the code slightly to maintain privacy, but let me know if that helps!

If you want to use CC instead of Bcc, then just change the code to:

```
recptOL.Type = olcc
```

Comment: I havent worked with Office 2016 yet, but I will keep it in mind, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating an Outlook object, try referencing the outlook library (Tools -> References and then select `Microsoft Outlook xx.x Object Library`). You can then reference it as below:

```
Sub SendAnEmail()

    Dim oOlApp As Outlook.Application: Set oOlApp = Outlook.Application
    Dim oMailItem As Outlook.MailItem: Set oMailItem = oOlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    oMailItem.To = "myemail@test.com"
    oMailItem.CC = ""
    oMailItem.BCC = "myemail@test.com"
    oMailItem.Subject = Sheet1.Cells(15, "D")
    oMailItem.HTMLBody = "Again .. testing"
    oMailItem.Display

    Set oMailItem = Nothing
    Set oOlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

You can either add this code in your sub or call this Sub from your Sub with parameters

Comment: I know where you are coming from, but I might have to deploy this on machines where the user is not able to activate references. At the moment, I am checking whether outlook is opened and running before executing this code. Any way around having to activate the reference manually?

Comment: I've just tried code similar to yours and it worked for me in Office Professional Plus 2013. I have the code in a `Class Module` that way I check if outlook is open when I initialize the class. Which version of office 2013 do you have?